Theories for "fuzzy" distributions
When calculating the probability density function for the quotients of adjacent values in an empirical time series, the image of the PDF looked like this:

It seems to resemble a lognormal distribution.
Question:

are there any established theories that deal with distributions that have a "fuzzy/fractal" probability density function as depicted above?

Edit:
the method of calculating the PDF was as follows:

sort the measured values $x[t]$ in ascending order to yield $x_i \le x_{i+1}$
remove from the sequence $x_i$ all $x_i:\, x_i=x_{i+1}$
let $x_j$ be the immediate successor of $x_i$; then we have $x_i\lt x_j$
set $PDF(x_i) = (j-i)/(x_j-x_i)$

the calculation of $PDF(x_i)$ resembles the standard definition of probability density functions, albeit vertically scaled with a constant factor.

How was the p.d.f. calculated based on the empirical data, in complete detail? What do you mean, exactly, by "the image of the PDF"?

It could also merely be the effect of one random sample over a smooth standard distribution, as most plottings of realized frequencies would look like.

@IosifPinelis the data was calculated in complete detail from ca 30k values of heart beat intervals. By the image of the PDF I mean the plot of the function and not an image in the mathematical sense.

I asked "How was the p.d.f. calculated based on the empirical data, in complete detail?", not how "the data was calculated".

@IosifPinelis sorry for the misconception; I have now added an informal description of the steps that were taken in order to calculate the depicted PDF

@ClaudeChaunier I have repeated the calculation with a lot of different datasets from similar measurements, so that phenomen appears to be "stable"

"description of the steps that were taken in order to calculate the depicted PDF" -- I don't see any such description.

@IosifPinelis the edit should now be visible...

I agree with Claude Chaunier that this is just a plot of what it looks like to sample from a standard distribution, not one with any special fractal properties.

@ManfredWeis : This is not how the density is consistently estimated or how it should be consistently estimated. Some kind of smoothing is needed; when it is done, this "fractal" mirage will likely disappear.

@IosifPinelis my usecase was to calculate statistical properties of a sample but I see that I should rather estimate what these properties would be if the measurements were repeatedly, resp for infinitely long time intervals. But still this doesn't rule out the theoretical possibility of fractal PDFs, or am I missing something?

As was noted in the comments, the observed "fractal/fuzzy" plot of the results of your calculation has hardly anything to do with the underlying pdf.
To estimate a statistical distribution or any of its features/parameters (such as the mean, the variance, the density), we have to assume a statistical model of the sampling procedure.
In particular, when the unknown density is estimated non-parametrically, it is usually assumed -- in order to get consistency -- that the density has some smoothness properties. Then a standard estimator of the density is a kernel estimator.
These points are illustrated in the image of a Mathematica notebook below. It shows a "fractal/fuzzy" plot (based on your "calculation" procedure) for what actually is a random sample from the standard normal distribution. It also shows a kernel estimate of the standard normal density.



very helpful explanation of the subtle differences that could easily get mixed up.
